# Access Laravel 4 composer package assets

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

I just added the Twitter Bootstrap via composer in Laravel 4 but im not sure how to actually link to files like `bootstrap-tooltip.js`, `bootstrap-transition.js` etc in my blade template.

This isn’t a question about the `{{HTML::}}` class, I know that is removed in version 4. I just want to know how to access media that is not stored in the `/public/` directory.

I guess if I was doing this manually I would have the js in the `/public/js/` directory but when installing the package via composer the files are stored at `/vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/`

It was a long shot and even feels wrong but I tried:

```
<script src="{{ path('vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js') }}"></script>
```

Hope that makes sense and someone can advise (I also hope im not being stupid and missing something really obvious).

Comment: +1, but what solution did you finally had? I'm in the same situation

Comment: I know this is a bit old but since somebody upvoted the question recently I thought I'd update (now that I'm a little wiser on this). As The answer suggests you should publish the assets using the artisan command. Their shouldn't be a need to link directly to the vendor files themselves. Their are cases where front end packages exist on packagist e.g twitter Bootstrap. These shouldn't really be used as packagist is really for PHP packages, not frontend packages. For that you should instead use something like http://bower.io which is a package manager for front end type assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help...

It would need some sort of composer post script running, similar to the one the Symfony Bootstrap uses

```
https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Composer/ScriptHandler.php
```

There is a Artisan command to move assets for packages but I'm not sure if it works with generic vendors

```
php artisan asset:publish vendor/package
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Although I was hoping for a more cohesive solution. Maybe it will be improved in future versions. Thanks again

Comment: Just remembered about this question and thought i'd update. Very soon after I added twitter bootstrap via packagist I realised this is the wrong way to deal with asset management and removed it. if you really need asset management something like Bower (http://bower.io/) should be used instead. For all other package based cases as Dave mentions, publish them